# Google Custom Site Search Not Tracking in Universal Analytics

Tags: search, google-analytics, universal-analytics

We upgraded to Universal Analytics about a year ago and since upgrading our Site Search isn't displaying the keywords within our Analytics account, or even tracking the number of times it is used.

This is a problem as a marketer as I like to know what people are looking for so that I can provide them relevant content.

All I can find on the Google blog is this: 
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2715510
'At this time, Google Custom Search Engine, is not compatible with Universal Analytics.'

Has anyone got any suggestions as to how I can get this data back? Are there any other custom site searches that I could use instead? Are Google even looking at this?

Answer (score 2):

Google CSE is using old _gaq calls for analytics, it can be mimicked by adding following code line at the end of universal GA snippet:

```
_gaq={push:function(){ga('send','pageview',arguments[0][1]);}}
```

Comment: This is absolutely the answer!  Nice one line solution to this problem!

Answer (score 0):

View - View settings - Site search settings is on and correctly tuned?

Comment: I can't find a 'View' or a 'View Settings' within my Google Analytics. Where can I look for this?

The site search was working until I upgraded to Google's Universal Analytics.

Comment: After upgrade You must change a GATC code from old one on new one.
View is located in Admin menu on the top.

Comment: The analytics is tracking absolutely everything else - just not the site search. Is the GATC as advised from the Universal upgrade.